# Longest common substring matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am very new with python and am struggling in creating a matrix that expresses the longest common substring. I am looking for a result like this: [LCS matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daZQ2.png)

This is my code so far.

```
def compute_lcs(X, Y):
    m = len(X)
    n = len(Y)
# An (m) times (n) matrix
    matrix = [[0] * (n) for _ in range(m)]
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if X[i] == Y[j]: 
                if i == 0 or j == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = 1
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1]+1
        else:
            matrix[i][j] = 0
    return matrix

b = compute_lcs('AACTGGCAG','TACGCTGGA')
for y in b:
    print (y)

Current Output:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0]

Expected Output:
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

However my result is a matrix that shows incorrect values. When I do the matrix by hand, the correct output looks like this: [Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWYEW.png). I feel like my logic makes sense, what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you please put the outputs as as part of your question instead of an image? It is easier to compare/see where things are messing up.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, to make things clear, the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem is not the same as the [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem. What you're trying to solve is the latter; better not to confuse the two.

Secondly, your `else` branches are not aligned under the appropriate `if` conditions. 
Whenever the strings match `X[i] == Y[j]`, we set the matrix element to 1 if the index i or j is 0 since i-1 or j-1 at 0 gives -1 (unfortunately, this is also the index for last item in Python) which is not what we want, otherwise we increment for higher indices i, j > 1.

Thirdly, your looping should start at 0 not 1 since we start from the first characters in the strings which are at indices 0:

```
def compute_lcs(X, Y):
   m = len(X)
   n = len(Y)
   # An (m) times (n) matrix
   matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)]
   for i in range(0, m):
      for j in range(0, n):
          if X[i] == Y[j]: 
              if i == 0 or j == 0:
                  matrix[i][j] = 1
              else:
                  matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1]+1
          else:
              matrix[i][j] = 0
  return matrix
```

To get the exact matrix shown in the expected output, you should swap the order of the arguments or transpose the matrix before printing. Note however that these are not necessary (swapping or transposing) and only serve for formatting purposes:

```
b = compute_lcs('TACGCTGGA', 'AACTGGCAG')
for y in b:
    print (y)
```

---

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much, that clears it up a lot. I didn't understand why sometimes things were set to 1 or 0 but your response makes it so simple.